# NPSP Campaign/Volunteer Jobs parent query

Tags: soql, npsp, parent-to-child

We are using NPSP Volunteers for Salesforce package.  I am trying to query camapainsg and all associated volunteer jobs.  The name of the child relationship, according to the UI, is 'Volunteer_Jobs'.  So I try and run this query:

```
select Name,
(select Name from Volunteer_Jobs__r) from Campaign
```

and I get the error:

**Didn't understand relationship 'Volunteer_Jobs__r' in FROM part of query call.**

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Could you be missing namespace prefix in the query? Looks like NPSP is a managed package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Volunteers for Salesforce is a managed package (and is not part of NPSP). You must include the namespace, `GW_Volunteers__`, prior to any reference to a packaged relationship.